# Websphere loses configuration after installing patch

Tags: java, configuration, websphere

I had on local machine Websphere 8.5.0.1
I just installed through Installation Manager a patch 8.5.0.2

I can't find all configurations previuosly set (data sources, shared libraries, etc...)

Is it normal? I missed to do some back up of configuration before?

I'm new on these about these concepts, juse began to learn Java / Eclipse / Websphere.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal. Technically, it's recommended to backup before applying maintenance but not to spill/restore any configuration.  8.5.0.2 itself is fantastically out of date, more than 6 years old.